# MVC Razor Additional of two integers?

Tags: razor

No's Parents :

```
@{
   foreach (var item in Model)
   {
  ((item.Mothers.Count) + (item.Fathers.Count)).ToString();
   }
}
```

*O/P: No's Parents:*

No's Parents :

```
@{
foreach (var item in Model)
   {
 item.Mothers.Count +item.Fathers.Count
   }
}
```

*O/p: No's Parents :0+0*

I trying to show o/p like, if parents(mother/ father) information not found then display with zero, if mother/ father information exists then display additioinal of Mother.count()+Father.Count().

what am i doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
            <div>   
            No's Students :@item.Students.Count()<br />
```

> **It works?**

```
            @{ var a = item.Mothers.Count().ToString ();
               var b = item.Fathers.Count().ToString ();
               var total = a.AsInt() + b.AsInt();
               }
            No's Parentsfdsfs :@total;
```

> **It is not working! why?**

```
            No's Parents :@{ ((item.Mothers.Count()) +   (item.Fathers.Count())).ToString ();} 

            <hr />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: when you say it works or doesn't work, what do you mean? Do you mean it won't compile? Do you mean you get a runtime error? What error do you get?

Comment: It works? giving me O/P No's Parents: 2
It is not working? giving me O/P: No's Parents: //empty showing
both cases no error occured.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the sum of both entities is 0, then take action on the result.

This will write "no parents" if both the mothers and fathers items are 0. Otherwise, it will write the number of parents.

```
@{
   foreach (var item in Model)
   {
    if(item.Mothers.Count == 0 && item.Fathers.Count == 0)
    {
        response.write("no parents");
    }else{
        response.write(((item.Mothers.Count) + (item.Fathers.Count)).ToString());
    }
   }
}
```